# selecting text in bash using ctrl + arrows?

Tags: bash

in other GUI based textboxes (like libreoffice or telegram messagebox) i can select the text with ctrl and arrow keys and cntrl + shift + arrow keys to select entire words. but in bash ternimal that don't work. is there a way to make it work?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/236158/tmux-vs-screen

Answer (score 0):

The terminal is a *terminal emulator*: it emulates a terminal. Thus, the default keybindings work similarly as they do in a text console terminal, a tty.

In the default terminal emulator of Ubuntu, gnome-terminal, you can set shortcut keys in the Preferences. However, you depend on what your terminal emulator program allows. For `gnome-terminal`, there are no options to set shortcut keys to select text, except for *select all text*. So what you are after will not be possible.

Still, you could set a key for Select all, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, a combination not used by bash. This copies the entire buffer, i.e., not only what you see. Even if you clear the screen with the bash shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, the entire buffer is still selected and can be copied to the clipboard. In contrast, the command `clear` not only clears the screen, but also the buffer.